# How come my code works separately but not when I merge it with my controller?

Tags: php, yii, google-api-php-client

I wrote this code in a `test.php` file.

```
<?php 

include ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/MySite/protected/MyYouTube/google/src/Google/autoload.php'); 

require_once ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/MySite/protected/MyYouTube/google/src/Google/Client.php');  
require_once ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/MySite/protected/MyYouTube/google/src/Google/Service/YouTube.php'); 
?>
```

If I go to this file like this: `localhost/MySite/protected/MyYouTube/test.php` it works, but if I copy the same code into my controller that is located under the same folder as `test.php`, I get this:

> include(Google_Service.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory

There are no conflicts with the imports. In fact, the controller and view can be empty and still I get the same thing.

Apparently that happens when `autoload.php` is not actually loaded.

How is it possible that when the code is integrated into the website it throws this error?

This is what the path to my site looks like:
      `localhost/MySite/index.php/user/view` **It seems that the way I visit the file matters.**

---

I tried several things. I tried importing the `test.php` into my view or my controller, and still I get the same error. I tried using `Yii::app()->basePath` and it gives the same problem.

The paths are correct, I have checked several times. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The include path is actual server path, not site path, if you use / at the beginning, you are telling it to look in the server root.

If you know the absolute path in the server you can use it like `/var/www/MySite` or `c:\mysite`if you don't know that then you use relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] works well with PHP 5.3, not sure if below check your version. Try removing the '/' before the MySite part, as the variable already does it for you so it might be printing like localhost//MySite, although I'm not sure if that should or shouldn't work. ]

Also the autoload php should be loaded with a require_once function, not with the include. Good luck!